What's the reason for g-dropping in songs?
Why are g's dropped in songs as in ing->in'? But it seems g's aren't always dropped. When does one sing without dropping g's?

Related questions and probable duplicates amongst these: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, and many more. Please read those and tell us whether they answer your question.

No none of them answers this question in terms of songs.  Therefore my question is unique and hasn't had an answer to it.

In this respect singing is no different from speech; -ing may be pronounced -in in certain dialects or when speaking informally. So you might hear it in pop or folk songs but not in more formal music.

Try to sing a g.

@feynman There is nothing unique about g-dropping in  songs.

@Greybeard There very much is, namely that it's often used by singers who don't speak accents that allow g-dropping. Voting to reopen. Please read questions carefully before casting a close vote so that we stop having to overturn them.

You need to provide examples. Why should we go and try to find them? It's not about dialects in singing.

@alphabet I presume that the asker is a non-native speaker who misunderstands what sorts of phenomena normally, even mandatorily, occur to the voiced ᴠᴇʟᴀʀ nasal phoneme /ŋ/ in the unstressed inflectional morpheme sadly spelt ‑ɪɴɢ under “allegro rules”. They are unlikely to be asking what happens to spring, sing, thing, rung, pink, bang when sung, nor even about finger, singer, harbinger, pinged, banger, banker, but rather about ONLY the 2nd not the 1st /ŋ/ in inking, singing, fingering, banging becoming the voiced ᴀʟᴠᴇᴏʟᴏᴀʀ nasal /n/: yet another spelling confusion.

@tchrist Yes, of course they're asking about the case of words like singing or something or running. But that phenomenon is not universal (particularly outside the US) and the asker presumably doesn't have it.

@alphabet Wikipedia seems to think it is very nearly universal: 1, 2. Notice that Wells says that this “exists in all communities where there is an English-speaking working class”, except in South Africa. Remember too that dropping the /g/ in singer but not in finger is also far more common than not. As currently phrased in the question, you cannot tell what is being asked.

@tchrist If you want to continue debating a point that I believe is clearly irrelevant to the question the asker has, we can do so in chat. I have an answer to the question (on what I consider its most obvious reading) and can post it if it gets reopened. See this post on Language Log. For information on the current situation in England, where this pronunciation is generally stigmatized, see Geoff Lindsey, English After RP pp. 73-74.

@tchrist this Language Log post may help explain why g-dropping is much more likely to happen in your accent (where those syllables contain the FLEECE vowel) than in many others (where they contain the KIT vowel).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yjyj8qnqkYI The Beatles, being from Liverpool but also due to rock music, drop their g's but not with every ing verb. One would have to listen to each occurrence to get a better feeling for this. [I did vote to re-open]

@alphabet I was going to post those but since I'm often rebuked for posting answers in comments I didn't. However, neither of those very informative posts g-dropping re singers mention that pronouncing ing in verbs like singing perhaps lengthens the sound awkwardly. n at the end is smoother than ŋ [ing], which can be awkward (?).

It's rainin', it's pourin', the old man's snorin'. He bumped his head and went to bed but couldn't get up in the mornin' Try singing that nursery rhyme pronouncing each and every -g and then try singing it without. It's possible but without the -gs, singing it is quicker and easier.

Of course in some cases there's no mystery here: the singer has an accent or dialect that "drops" g's (i.e. replacing word-final /ŋ/ with /n/ in some contexts) and they sing in this same accent.
But that's not the only case: as this post from Language Log notes, some artists (like Taylor Swift) drop g's when singing but not when speaking in e.g. interviews. This is mainly attributable to them performing in genres "traditionally based on varieties of English where g-dropping is normal."
There are a number of other features like this; as Dave Huxtable notes, in pop songs the PRICE vowel is often pronounced as a monophthong, a feature typically associated with Southern American English and AAVE, even by singers from Britain who would never use that pronunciation in ordinary speech. This is, again, due to the influence of speakers of such dialects on the genres in question.
(One assumes that this is also why you sometimes hear pop songs that are non-rhotic but still have an R-colored NURSE vowel. Of course these features don't mean that these singers sound at all like Southerners or AAVE speakers singing in their own accents; otherwise they tend to sound more-or-less like General American. But I digress.)

We drop the g because Singing 101: You go nasal-y if you don’t.

Monophthongs sound better than diphthongs when you're singing. So if you can change an /aɪ/ to an /aː/ without it sounding wrong, you might as well.
